# Working with URI in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, uri

I have a URL like below :

`http://localhost:1692/fa/Help.aspx#Help`

the code below returns that :

```
    alert(document.URL);
```

I only want to get the `http://localhost:1692` part of this URL.

How can I get it with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: `alert(window.location.host)`

Comment: my problem is about that port...some url s like this local url have that port.

Comment: ok, so sorry -> alert(window.location.host) is my answer.

Comment: @steveax plz put your comment as answer.

Comment: If you want the protocol too, then Esailija's answer is the ticket. [MDN on window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`alert( location.protocol + "//" + location.host )`

Answer (score 0):

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host
```

And, if you want, you have these other properties:

- `hash`
- `search` - url querystring
- `hostname` - only the hostname (without port)
- `port` - only the port number
- `pathname` - the local url